# C# Nested Tables in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm trying to design a table that has 3 additional tables in the last cell. Like this.
[image: Nested table example]

I've managed to get the first nested table into row 4, but my second nested table is going into cell(1,1) of the first table.

[image: Incorrect nested table example]

```
var wordApplication = new Word.Application();
wordApplication.Visible = true;
var wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add();
var docRange = wordDocument.Range();
docRange.Tables.Add(docRange, 4, 1);
var mainTable = wordDocument.Tables[1];
mainTable.set_Style("Table Grid");
mainTable.Borders.Enable = 0;
mainTable.PreferredWidthType = Word.WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthPercent;
mainTable.PreferredWidth = 100;
docRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);

var phoneRange = mainTable.Cell(4, 1).Range;
phoneRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
phoneRange.Tables.Add(phoneRange, 3, 2);

var phoneTable = mainTable.Cell(4, 1).Tables[1];
phoneTable.set_Style("Table Grid");
phoneTable.Borders.Enable = 0;
phoneTable.AutoFitBehavior(Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent);
phoneTable.Rows.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;

phoneRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
```

I've tried collapsing the range, adding in a paragraph then collapsing the range again. No luck. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996242/how-adding-multi-tables-on-word-with-net) and many similar ones, but I must be missing something.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It usually helps in situation like these to add a line in your code: phoneRange.Select(); and having code execution end with that. Take a look at where the Range actually is. My gut feeling is you're definitely on the right track, but may need to move the Range.End back a character or something like that: phoneRange.MoveEnd(ref oWdUnitCharacter, ref oMinusOne); FWIW your bigger problem may turn out getting the tables nicely next to one another in the same row.

Comment: Indeed, the biggest problem is to align the nested tables next to each other. You would have to use floating tables to do so (`Table.Rows.WrapAroundText = true;`)

Comment: @CindyMeister Adding in `phoneRange.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
phoneRange.Tables.Add(phoneRange, 3, 1);` results in error 
_the object refers to the end of a table row_
-2 results in the table going into the row above. I've tried various combinations but haven't got much further. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: And did you try my suggestion about selecting the range and stopping execution so you can see exactly where things are? Then try getting the result you need using the keyboard until you hit on the right combination. I DID test my suggestion and it DID work in my test environment (as far as inserting the second table in the same cell) - but without more detailed information from you we can't duplicate the test environment. So you need to do some research yourself within the Word UI...

Comment: @Dirk: Yes, I thought about that but I'm skeptical whether floating tables will restrict themselves reliably to another table cell... The better way, quite frankly, would be to split the table cell into four cells. But then, of course, one runs into the issues with being able to work with rows and columns when the table isn't "even"...

Comment: @Cindy, sorry, wasn't sure about the phoneRange.Select(); but figured it out now, the cursor is going to outside the 3rd row, http://imgur.com/DXHcjOH. I'll keep trying after the weekend, don't know why it's not working likes yours :-(

Comment: Outside the third row? Odd... Try setting a new Range object to phoneTable.Range then collapse that to its end point. Is that any better?

Comment: @Cindy, thank you! That worked. If you want to convert the comment to a solution, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually helps in situation like these to add a line in your code: phoneRange.Select(); and having code execution end with that. Take a look at where the Range actually is. Now you can test using the keyboard where the Range needs to be in order to insert the next table successfully.

Since you say phoneRange selects outside the third row, rather than working with phoneRange try setting a new Range object to phoneTable.Range then collapse it to its end-point.